# Django Queryset on Cassandra User Defined Type throws Type Error

Tags: python, django, cassandra, django-queryset, datastax

I am using a combination of the [DataStax Python Driver](https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/) and the [Django Cassandra Engine](https://pypi.org/project/django-cassandra-engine/) to communicate with Cassandra through a Django app.

Here is how I define a model with User Defined Type columns (example only):

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.usertype import UserType
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel

class UserAddress(UserType)
    street = columns.Text()
    number = columns.Integer()

class User(DjangoCassandraModel):
    __table_name__ = 'users'

    user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    name = columns.Text()
    address = columns.UserDefinedType(UserAddress)


class Meta:
    managed = False
    get_pk_field = 'user_id'
```

I'm attempting to query this model with the following call:

```
User.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
```

which throws this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.py", line 1043, in to_python

if copied_value[name] is not None or isinstance(field, BaseContainerColumn):

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This error originates from the `UserDefinedType` class declaration, specifically this function:

```
    def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return

    copied_value = deepcopy(value)
    for name, field in self.user_type._fields.items():
        if copied_value[name] is not None or isinstance(field, BaseContainerColumn):
            copied_value[name] = field.to_python(copied_value[name])

    return copied_value
```

It would seem to me that the Django Cassandra Engine, which includes the `DjangoCassandraQuerySet` class, is not playing well with the `UserDefinedType` class, though I'm not sure why.

I've not had any problems with these libraries up until now and I find it strange that an operation like this wouldn't be supported. I'm hoping I've missed a configuration somewhere, or at least that the issue is resolvable.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine/issues/86#issuecomment-595592483) on the Django Cassandra Engine issues page for the solution to this problem.

It appears that the DataStax Python Driver interprets unregistered types as plain dictionaries causing them to be deserialized as a series of tuples instead of a proper dictionary, explaining the error message.

The solution is to register the UDTs whenever a connection is initiated. This must be done every time as it does not seem to persist.

To do this, add this code after your UDT class declarations:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.usertype import UserType    
from django.db import connections
from cassandra.cluster import UserTypeDoesNotExist

class UserAddress(UserType)
    street = columns.Text()
    number = columns.Integer()

user_types = [ UserAddress ]
database_name = 'DjangoDBName'
keyspace = 'CassandraKeyspace'
connection = connections[database_name]

for udt in user_types:
  try:
    connection.connection.cluster.register_user_type(keyspace, udt.type_name(), udt)
  except UserTypeDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Alternatively, you could add this code to an `__init__.py` file if you have a package of UDT class declarations.

Why the Django Cassandra Engine doesn't register these types automatically, I have no idea.